# How do I get the author from SyndicationFeed object where feed has a namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, syndication-feed

I have an RSS feed. I am using the ASP.NET SyndicationFeed object to trawl through this feed.

In this feed the authors of each post have the element name `<dc:creator>`. How do I get the data from this feed when the author are not nicely in the  tag like it should be?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the following properties: SyndicationFeed.Authors, SyndicationFeed.Contributors, SyndicationItem.Authors and SyndicationItem.Contributors. In my experience it is common that these fields contain no values, out of 130 RSS feeds I pull into a custom RSS reader only 11 feeds have valid values.

//

// Summary:
        //     Gets a collection of authors of the feed.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A collection of System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationPerson objects
        //     that represents the authors of the feed.

```
public Collection<SyndicationPerson> Authors { get; }
```

//
        // Summary:
        //     Gets a collection of the contributors to the feed.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A collection of System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationPerson objects
        //     that represents the contributors to the feed.

public Collection Contributors { get; }

Comment: So there's no way of actually getting fields that don't have "standard" node names?

Comment: Also, I've just updated the question to add the "code" in as it was just showing up as double quotes.

Comment: Using LINQ to XML or XPath to isolate the specific note and value is arguably just quick and easy.